# FIle upload code FIle Exist Validation Code in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my Controller for file upload :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(AdulLiteracyTeachers adulliteracyteachers, HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
        {
            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
            {
                string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/"), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);
                adulliteracyteachers.Image = file.FileName;
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.AdulLiteracyTeachers.Add(adulliteracyteachers);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.DistID = new SelectList(db.Districts, "DistID", "DistName", adulliteracyteachers.DistID);
            return View(adulliteracyteachers);
        }
```

How Can I put the Check If file already exists upload another ?

Answer (score 0):

suppose in View:

```
<input type="file" id="FileUpload" name="FileUpload"/>
```

you need to do that in action:

```
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Uploads/"), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));

if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{ 
    //Other code

this.ModelState.AddModelError("FileUpload", "File Already exists");

return View(adulliteracyteachers);
}

else
{
 // upload and save in db
}
```

Comment: it should work you check in if that if file exists set Error in Model that File not exists make sure model has property namely FileUpload